# Beeping over pc speaker without superuser permissions

Tags: c, linux

Currently I am using the following code to put out beep sounds over the PC speaker in Linux with C.

```
int speaker_desc;

// Returns 0 on success
int register_speaker() {
    return (speaker_desc = open("/dev/console", O_RDONLY)) == -1;
}

void unregister_speaker() {
    close(speaker_desc);
}

void beep(int pulse_length, int duration) {
    int arg = (duration << 16) | (pulse_length & 0xffff);
    ioctl(speaker_desc, KDMKTONE, arg);
}
```

Now the problem is that `register_speaker()` fails if the program is not run under superuser. Is there a work-around to this? Because I am used to being able to operate the PC-speaker with user-privileges under Windows and the regular `BEL`-character also beeps without superuser.

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60646) says that `dev/tty` is not restricted to root by default. I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: The original beep.c  uses the      `KIOCSOUND`  ioctl  to make the beep and also opens the console writeonly `if((console_fd = open("/dev/console", O_WRONLY)) == -1) ....`  So you may want to check out this source code .
http://www.johnath.com/beep/beep.c

Comment: Is your program running on the console?  If not you might not be able to access it without being superuser

Comment: @unwind I tried /dev/tty but ioctl does absolutely nothing or at least it doesn't beep without raising an error

Comment: @user865368 Read-only or write-only did not change anything. And KIOCSOUND would only be useful if I could open the device in the first place. I downloaded beep.c, compiled it, did not work without root. I guess it is impossible at this point...

Comment: is your user member of group `audio`? `# usermod -a -G audio <username>`